# Unable to capture desired groups and kick out the rest

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I've written a pattern within regex to capture only this two `456jkl`,`jkl456` among `456jkl`,`jkl456`,`456`,`jkl` but when i execute the script, it get all four of them. Where I'm going wrong?

My script:

```
import re

content = """456jkl, 456, jkl, jkl456"""

item = [item for item in re.findall('((?:jkl|456)+)',content)]
print(item)
```

I'm getting:

```
['456jkl', '456', 'jkl', 'jkl456']
```

Expected output:

```
['456jkl', 'jkl456']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex currently matches either pattern, but you want it to match both patterns. You can use string formatting to do so:

```
a = '456'
b = 'jkl'

re.findall(rf'\b(?:{a}{b}|{b}{a})\b', content)
['456jkl', 'jkl456']
```

Which means "match *only* this sequence, or its reverse". With this, (spurious?) patterns such as "456456" and "jkljkl" will not be matched.

(Works with python3.6+ f-strings.)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex reads `(jkl|456)+` which means match either `jkl` or `456` and do this at least one time. That's what gives you the 2nd and 3rd match. You would need `(jkl|456){2}` instead which means "match it exactly two times".